# Can you reorder columns in Report designer (bids 2005)

Tags: visual-studio-2005, reporting-services, rdl, bids

I have a reporting service report and I can't seem to figure out how to reorder the columns in the table control. Is this possible with editing the rdl file directly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can highlight a column (make sure to hightlight the entire column) then rightclick->CUT.  Then highlight another column and rightclick->PASTE.  The column will paste itself to the left of the column you had highlighted.

This is the quickest way to re-order a column.

**Instructions for Visual Studio 2010 SP1:**

In order to get the "Cut/Copy/Paste options to show up, you must highlight the header and detail row of the column by first clicking in the header row, then *shift-clicking* in the detail row.  This will give you a grey outline around both. If you have the grey empty box at the top highlighted, then the cut will not work.

You will also need to pre-insert a column before pasting, and delete the blank column after pasting.

Comment: I see none of those options.  Are you thinking of Excel?

Comment: No.  No I am not. I was thinking about the Report Designer.

Comment: You have to right click on the highlited border, not the column itself.

Comment: In the 2005 version you could cut and insert the copied column without pre-inserting a destination column. I guess the aim for 2008 is to enhance our lives by ensuring we don't run out of busy work.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you can copy and paste the contents of existing columns into new columns, though this isn't exactly what I looking for.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do?  Are you trying to re-order them programatically?